# Concerns/mixins in controllers - issue with variables/methods visibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have a several controllers which work with lists of model instances, and once I've done one controller, I've decided to move it all in concern to just reuse code.

```
module ListController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  #code
end
```

But it brought me to several issues.

First of all, I need this controllers to work with different resources. For example:

```
module ListController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    doll =  self.name.to_s.match(/^(\w+)ListController/)[1]
    @resource = doll.downcase
    @klass = doll.singularize.constantize
    define_method("new_#{@resource}_list")  do
      if appropriate_quantity?
        quantity=params[:quantity].to_i
        array = Array.new(quantity) do
          @klass.new
        end
        instance_variable_set("@#{@resource}", array)
      elsif invalid_entry_cookie?
        invalid_entries_from_redis(@klass)
      else
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So when module included, I get the name of controller, find part before ListController, and by my own convention it leads me to needed model and resource:

```
doll =  self.name.to_s.match(/^(\w+)ListController/)[1]#=>Students
@resource = doll.downcase #=>students
@klass = doll.singularize.constantize #=>Student
```

Seems to be nice. But

1) module itself doesn't see instance variables. So `@resource` and `@klass` loose it's visibility after line `define_method`, and everything looses it's point. I can't make module flexible enough to be reusable without this variables to be visible all along included block. Solution?

2) with included, do I pass `@resource` and `@klass` to each controller? I don't like this, as they just don't needed there. I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use `before_action` filter to set up these instance variables as follows:

```
module ListController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    # Set instance vars in the current class
    init_proc = Proc.new do |c|
      doll =  c.class.name.match(/^(\w+)ListController/)[1]
      c.instance_variable_set(:@resource, doll.downcase)
      c.instance_variable_set(:@klass, doll.singularize.constantize)
    end

    # Run the above proc before each page load this method is declared in
    before_action(init_proc)

    # Make @resource and @klass available right now
    init_proc.call(self)

    define_method("new_#{@resource}_list")  do
      if appropriate_quantity?
        quantity=params[:quantity].to_i
        array = Array.new(quantity) do
          @klass.new
        end
        instance_variable_set("@#{@resource}", array)
      elsif invalid_entry_cookie?
        invalid_entries_from_redis(@klass)
      else
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
end
```

2) You can include such concern in `ApplicationController` to avoid including everywhere.